# Simplest way to test authentication in spring security application

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

I have a simple method to authenticate user on my web application

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    if (name.contains("@mydomain.com")) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
        return auth;
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password");
    }
}
```

I'd like to know is there a way to test it (preferably in JUnit) without using compilcated tools like MockMvc ( https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security )

Comment: Can you explain exactly what do you want to test ?
What is your acceptance test ?
You want to test your algorithm or the spring security behavior in integration ?

Comment: I want to test my algorithhm . Basically i want to be sure that any username that contains "*@mydomain.com"  will allow me to authenticate

Comment: You could mock or stub the Authentication object.
In a first test, you will do it with expected data for authentication success.
 In your second test, you will do it with expected data for authentication failure. 
In your unit tests, you will transmit the mock/stubbed authentication with the  predefined behavior. Look at Mockito for example

Comment: @davidhxxx but how to use it with my custom authenticate function